# Mocking query_params using responses and pytest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mocking, pytest, python-responses

I would like some help to mock a query_param using responses and pytest.

I have this view:

```py
@api_view(["GET"])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def get_code_and_extra(request):
    code = request.GET.get("code", "")
    extra = request.GET.get("extra", "")
    if code and extra:
        # do something
        return HttpResponse("", status=200)
    return HttpResponse("", status=400)
```

And my test mocked:

```py
    @responses.activate
    def test_receive(self, db, client):
        responses.add(
            responses.GET,
            "https://test.com/?code=some-code&extra=extra",
            json={},
            status=200,
            content_type="application/json",
        )
        resp = client.get(reverse("my-url"))
        assert resp.status_code == 200
```

When I run my test works, but the view does not receive the query_params. I would like to pass it so that the test works as expected.

A little more context: this view serves as a webhook that receives these parameters from another site. The view is working, but I wanted to have this test.